# Monitoring ASP/COM+ application performance in Windows 2003/IIS 6.0

Tags: performance, com, asp-classic, iis-6, windows-server-2003

We are running a website using **Active Server Pages & COM+ components**. The ASP pages call COM+ components which in turn communicates with external systems and respond to ASP page requests.

We find that the application becomes slow over a period of time and requires restarts (like in couple of days). The website runs on good hardware and does not have huge traffic and so we believe it's not a capacity issue.

The application was written in ASP 3.0, VB 6.0 (COM) by an external vendor who does not support us any more. This being the situation, we want to figure out where the problem is by monitoring the ASP website and COM+ components' performance.

Hence my questions:

- Which all performance counters are
  the best to monitor for this case?
- At what interval should the counters
  be logged?
- How long are the counters monitored
  before you start analysing them? I
  realise this could vary for
  different applications but is there
  a general guideline?
- Once the counters are collected, how
  can one make sense out of it? Manual
  analysis using MS Excel or is there
  any good tool recommended? What's
  your experience on this?

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425/what-is-the-best-way-to-interpret-perfmon-analysis-into-application-specific-ob#158314).

You should start with the PAL Perfmon_Template_for_System_Overview.htm settings file and add the following Active Server Pages counters:

- Errors During Script Runtime
- Errors From ASP Preprocessor
- Requests Executing
- Requests Queued
- Sessions Total
- Errors From Script Compilers
- Debugging Requests
- Request Execution Time
- Request Wait Time
- Requests/Sec
- Requests Total
- Requests succeeded
- Requests Failed Total
- Template Cache Hit Rate
- Process (inetinfo) Private Bytes

The template's default sampling interval of 15 seconds should be good enough, provided you monitor long enough. If you have hour(s) of peak usage during the day, it may be good enough to just monitor during that time; you're just looking for trends to help you focus your troubleshooting.

The PAl tool comes with analyzers for IIS 5.0 and 6.0 out of the box, but not classic ASP. You can create a new analyzer (called a threshold file in PAL) to include analysis for ASP. The code's too long to post here, but if you're interested, leave me a comment and we'll work out how I can send you what I have.

Also, if you have the Enterprise Edition of Visual Studio, you can use the [Visual Studio Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728806(VS.71).aspx) (VSA) to trace through all the ASP and COM calls. It does a pretty nice job of profiling where the time's being spent, and you can include Perfmon counters to monitor to see what's going on at the system level as well.

Comment: Hi Patrick,

Thanks for the post. Its fantastic! As you mentioned could you please send me the code for the threshold file to include analysis for ASP? If its alright, please email me at manjitkmohan@gmail.com

Many Thanks,
Nahom

Comment: Nahom, no problem, I hope it helps :)

Comment: @PatrickCuff wow long time since this post!  Any chance you still have this classic ASP threshold file?  Would be very useful to me? mat41@yahoo.com

Comment: @NahomTijnam incase Pat isn't around do you still have this classic ASP threshold file kicking around?

Comment: @Mat41; I don't have my threshold file anymore since we upgraded to PAL version 2.3.2 (http://pal.codeplex.com/), which now includes a threshold file for Active Server Pages.

Comment: @PatrickCuff than you for your reply.  After playing with PAL I discovered this, great!  I am trialing PAL on a 2003 server however after around 2 hours I am unable to get any .html output like the amazing example I found on the codeplex site.  Do you have any experience running this on a 2003 server?  All I am able to get running is the .blg file.  Any tips?

Comment: @Mat41; You don't need to run PAL on the server, it can run on your desktop. You first need to create a PerfMon log file, then load that log into PAL. I've done this with PerfMon logs from 2003 and 2008 R2 servers. I use logs in the CSV format, but it should work with binary files as well.