# Com+ Performance Counters in 2008

Tags: asp.net, performance, com+, perfmon, legacy-app

I have a COM+ application which is called by a series of ASP Pages.   I found this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304473/monitoring-asp-com-application-performance-in-windows-2003-iis-6-0) which suggested the following were the ideal set of metrics to monitor:

- Errors During Script Runtime
- Errors From ASP Preprocessor
- Requests Executing
- Requests Queued
- Sessions Total
- Errors From Script Compilers
- Debugging Requests
- Request Execution Time
- Request Wait Time
- Requests/Sec
- Requests Total
- Requests succeeded
- Requests Failed Total
- Template Cache Hit Rate
- Process (inetinfo) Private Bytes

Is this still prevalent in IIS 8.5?

Also, they made mention of a tool called PAL and shared a link on codeplex, however,  PAL has been moved off of codeplex, and is now available on Git [Here](https://github.com/clinthuffman/PAL).  Any insights from someone who may have recently had to track Perfmon stats for a COM+ application are welcomed.

Thanks!
Dustin

Comment: define "ideal". What's the goal? You can measure whatever you like, but it depends what you want to know, and what you want to do about what you know.

Comment: My goal in this is to get a very 'baseline' set of metrics that I could deploy for ALL .NET based applications within my enviornment.    For example:  I know that Requests Queued would be important to know because potentially it may lead us to understand the Request Queue Limit may need to be raised within our machine.config file.   

Not something that would only be specific to a particular application, but a very bare set that for ALL .NET applications someone should be monitoring.